# Elasticsearch Date Histogram Aggregation - get buckets by N count

Tags: elasticsearch, date-histogram

I need to get from elasticsearch Date Histogram with N buckets. I now that i can get data by interval for example. 1 month - but i need to get date where interval is undefined, but i now te count of buckets - and interval must be calculated by elasticsearch.

It is possible?

I din`t find answer here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html

Sorry for my english.

PS.
I can do that by create addon request (get date_min, date_max and calculate interval before i send proper request), but 2 request are worse than 1 request ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported by elasticsearch yet. See [issue 9572](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/9572).